# Getting the field of Contact from Case

Tags: apex, soql

I just wanna ask how to get the field of contact from Name. I want to get the Contact Name of Contact where it is look up fields from Case I tried this one. But using `newCase.ContactId = matchingContacts[0].Id;` will not make me insert a case. What I want to achieve is to get the Contact Name field from Case to put get the sender name.

```
Contact[] matchingContacts = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Name = :email.fromName];  

Case newCase = new Case();
if(toAddresses.size()>0){
    newCase.Description = email.plainTextBody;
    newCase.Subject = email.subject;
    newCase.ContactId = matchingContacts[0].Id;
    ^^^^ It is not Working ^^^
}
```

Comment: Hi @RemundoKaber, welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help] and read [ask].

Comment: Sorry I am new in asking sorry about that

Comment: No problem. I'm sorry I don't understand the question. What is the problem exactly? And what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a Case and Contact. In Contact there is Contact Name that is Related to Case. I want to get the Field Contact Name From Contact to display in Case

Comment: Your code is supposed to work. What do you mean when you say " It is not Working"?

Comment: Are you sure that the contact is being returned from the query?  Or that the conditions are being met?

Answer (score 0):

Your query shouldn't be looking for `Name = :email.fromName`. Instead, email address is considered an `externalId` for contact. That's what your WHERE condition in your query should be using. Case will be looking for the contactId. That's what you need it to return based on the email address.

```
Contact[] matchingContacts = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact WHERE email = :fromAddress];
```